# loop append variable in php?

Tags: php, loops, variables

I dont know if this is possible but can you create a variable loop?

I want to create many variables in an if condition

```
if($session[hello]){
$array1 = array("");
$array2 = array("");
$array3 = array("");
$array4 = array("");
$array5 = array("");
}
```

but since I have more I want to write it like this:

```
 if($session[hello]){
for($a = 1; $a <= 5; $a++){
$array + $a = array("");
}
```

But its not working and I cant figure out how this might be possible.

is there an alternative?

thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want the previous array to be appended to the next?

Comment: the expected output is when the original variables are used else where in the code, they dont produce errors when some of them are missing... if that makes sense

Comment: "the expected output is when the original variables are used else where in the code, they dont produce errors when some of them are missing". Where is "elsewhere"? Inside a function? Otherwise, @b0s3's answer should be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
if($session[hello]){
  for($a = 1; $a <= 5; $a++){
     ${'array' . $a} = array("");
  }
}
```

Don't why you want it this way but using an array would be better.

```
if($session[hello]){
  for($a = 1; $a <= 5; $a++){
     $array[$a] = array("");
  }
}
```

And access it like `$array[1]` or `$array[2]` etc.

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestions. maybe it would help if I explain the whole reason why I am doing it. I have a whole bunch of data from database that I want to echo out from an array in the code. and my solution to "null" data that would give me 'undefined offset' errors is to create a condition that if they dont exist, to turn that variable into an empty array instead of an null object. am I just going about it all wrong?

Comment: Yes you're probably doing it wrong, you should just check if the variable is set using http://php.net/isset

Comment: Why not simply use `isset` or `empty` accordingly?

Comment: yes! i just looked it up and empty is what i needed. ty